# How to create virtual folder with mod_rewrite similar ln -s Unix

Tags: php, apache, unix, mod-rewrite, ln

Previously was using command ln for create virtual folder.

```
cd public
ln -s ../app/assets/ assets

~ public > ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 carlosmontalvo  admin   14 May 15 12:21 assets -> ../app/assets/
```

But I want to do with mod_rewrite

I tested with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?assets(.*) ../app/assets$1 [P] #here
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

but this does not work

Tree Directory

```
├── app
│    └─ assets
│       ├── images
│       ├── javascripts
│       │   └── application.js
│       └── stylesheets
│           └── application.css
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── assets -> ../app/assets/
│   ├── index.php
│   └── robots.txt
```

could help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. RewriteRules can only rewrite to locations within the `DocumentRoot`. Why would you do this anyway? The symlink solution has less overhead and will therefor be faster than the RewriteRule solution.

Comment: You've never seen a framework with symlink so I thought it using mod_rewrite

Comment: Lithium (li3) recommends using symlinks for the assets. It has a default build in router that let's PHP serve the requested file for development purposes, but they recommend against that for production as it's a waste of PHP threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute paths.

```
Alias /assets/ /www/app/assets/

<Directory "/www/app/assets/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

should work provided Apache can access the files.

There's no reason to use `mod_rewrite` but:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /www/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /www/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)$ /www/app/assets/$1 [L]
```

should work as well.